# Cloud 9 Rails "No application seems to be running here" run time error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, runtime-error, cloud9-ide

I'm developing a simple Rails application using Cloud 9.

Everytime I run the application I get this error in the Cloud 9 browser

```
No application seems to be running here!
```

I researched this and I can't figure out why. I used

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

to launch the server. This was done in the root directory of the application. I have installed all the Rails gems/bundles needed.

When I run the application I'm getting a message in the terminal saying

```
my code is running at htttps://......... example
```

when I click the link is when I see the error.

This is the response from the terminal after I try start the server:

```
$ rails server –b $IP –p $PORT

Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/–b (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `try_require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/dublinapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/dublinapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/dublinapp/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/dublinapp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try removing Gemfile.lock and bundle install, and double try rails s -b $IP -p $PORT

Comment: Could be that another process is already attached to port 8080. Try [restarting your workspace](https://docs.c9.io/docs/restarting-your-workspace) or post about it at https://community.c9.io and you'll get help there.